# Required reviews completed

Tags: publications

I have submitted a paper and I received a request for major revisions.

The first time the status changed from "under review" to "with editor". 
After that I submitted a revised version of the paper. Now the status has changed from "under review" to "required reviews completed".

- Why first time it wasn't shown this status?
- How many days does it usually take to change the status from "required reviews completed" to next status?

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking. What do you mean by "first time"? On your original submission? Are you just asking how long it takes for revisions to be evaluated by the editor?

Comment: Yes, original submission. I want to know about the differenc between with editor and required reviews of completed after under review. Before revision the editor mentioned we are interested to publish work and comment for reviewer questions. Is it positive sign. Also time taken to evaluate reviewer recommendation by editor

Comment: *Why first time it wasn't shown this status?* – What makes you sure about this?

Comment: I don't know why first time it wasn't shown

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this means it has passed to the associate editor to decide what to do with the reviews.  In my experience the deadline for that action is typically about a week from the time the final review is available, but of course if the editor is otherwise occupied, it might take a while longer.  Patience!

Comment: what does it mean decision in process  status

Comment: Most likely, the AE has now made a recommendation, and the EIC has to process it.

Comment: How much time does it takes? The status has been showing decision in process for last two days. Is it positive sign.

Comment: Neutral.  Just means it's time for the next step.  Maybe a week or two.  Read the page describing the submission process.

Comment: What happens if one reviewer suggest accept and other reviewer suggest reject. The editorial board says it should become acceptable.

Comment: Is minor modification sent another round of review

Comment: Up to the editor in case of disagreement.

Comment: I received comments, one reviewer accepted and the other reviewer rejected. Editor adked for minor modification and I submitted to editor. Editor now sent again for review. What will happen now.

Comment: Read the FAQ. This is getting rather silly.